# Accessing fields for accountName/password

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working on a simple Spring application for monitoring workouts. I'm using a small MongoDB database for handling my accountName/password/firstName/lastName (basic account info). I'm trying to handle login right now, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the fields correctly to do a simple password check (the data is hosted at mlab.com).

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bdc7952b1c6ac606802ca69"
},
"accountName": "testAccount",
"password": "hockey",
"firstName": "Test",
"lastName": "Tester"
}
```

Creating/deleting the account info hasn't been a problem. But I can't seem to figure out how to pull accountName/password fields to do a check against what the user inputs. I've tried using the BasicDBObject and running a query, but it never seems to return anything.

edit:
for example, I've seen examples like this in other threads:

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(accountName, "password");
    DBCursor cursor = db.find(query);
```

the accountName parameter in my basicDBObject is the account name the user entered. My understanding, which seems to be wrong, is that when I assign a cursor to this query I should be able to get the "password" associated with that accountName in my documents on mlab. I get compiling errors since the return type on my db.find(query) is not a DBCursor.

Here is how my db is declared/accessed:

```
   private MongoCollection<Document> db;
   MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI(MONGO_URL);
   MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
   db = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase()).getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME);
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse that string correctly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. see my edit - I can't really get anything to return to work with at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can imagine `BasicDBObject` as a json, so when you are making this

`new BasicDBObject(accountName, "password");`

it would represent something like this

`{[accountName]: "password"}`

whatever is in `accountName` becomes the key and `"password"` becomes the value.

Probable what you want is to search for the `accountName` and have the `password` field as a projection.

```
MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI(MONGO_URL);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
DBCollection db = mongoClient.getDB(uri.getDabase()).getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("accountName", accountName);
BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject("password", 1);
DBCursor cursor = db.find(query, projection);
```

This was the old way of doing the query, the alternative uses `Bson` instead of  `BasicDBObject`

```
private MongoCollection<Document> db;
MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI(MONGO_URL);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
db = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase()).getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME);

Bson query = Filters.eq("accountName", accountName)
Bson projection = Projections.include("password")
FindIterable<Document> iterator = db.find(query).projection(projection)
```

The problem you had is your were mixing those two options.

Comment: thanks for the response. now that you mention it, the DB collection might be where I'm having the issue, see my edit.

Comment: @Polyphase29 I edited my answer, I think you were mixing different ways of using mongo from java

Comment: Thanks again. So, this code compiles, but now how do I access it to do the password check? I'm trying to iterate through but I can't seem to get any output. I'm testing with account/password combos I know are on the DB, and others that aren't.

Comment: I guess you are doing something similar to `for(Document doc : iterator) doc.getString("password")`, that should give you the password, also instead of iterating you could do `Document doc = iterator.first()` if you care only about the first result